# Cannot catkinify Baxter SDK

Tags: ros, catkin, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

This is the first time I ask for a question in the Forum, I looked for this question in the search bar, but my problem didn't specifically appeared.

I'm having troubles with the Step 5 of this tutorial: [Workstation Setup](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/Workstation_Setup). In this step, it says "Install Baxter Research Robot SDK", and I'm installing the current recommended installation: 1.0 Source; with ROS Groovy, in Ubuntu 12.04.

The features of my notebook are:

-Intel® Core™ i5-4210U CPU @ 1.70GHz × 4
-3,8 GiB
-Kernel Linux 3.13.0-43-generic
-64-bit arquitecture processor

First, I sourced the ROS setup with

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash
```

Then, when I try to build and install with catkin, the Terminal throws me this:

```
root@pablo-Latitude-3440:/home/pablo/ros_ws# catkin_make
Base path: /home/pablo/ros_ws
Source space: /home/pablo/ros_ws/src
Build space: /home/pablo/ros_ws/build
Devel space: /home/pablo/ros_ws/devel
Install space: /home/pablo/ros_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/pablo/ros_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/pablo/ros_ws/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target baxter_examples_gencfg
[  7%] [ 10%] Built target baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target baxter_interface_gencfg
[ 15%] Built target baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 43%] Built target baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 44%] [ 44%] [ 44%] Generating C++ code from baxter_maintenance_msgs/TareEnable.msg
Generating C++ code from baxter_maintenance_msgs/UpdateSource.msg
[ 70%] Generating C++ code from baxter_core_msgs/EndEffectorProperties.msg
Built target baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 71%] Generating C++ code from baxter_maintenance_msgs/CalibrateArmData.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
make[2]: *** [/home/pablo/ros_ws/devel/include/baxter_maintenance_msgs/UpdateSource.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
[ 72%] make[2]: *** [/home/pablo/ros_ws/devel/include/baxter_maintenance_msgs/TareEnable.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/home/pablo/ros_ws/devel/include/baxter_core_msgs/EndEffectorProperties.h] Error 1
make[2]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
Generating C++ code from baxter_core_msgs/AnalogOutputCommand.msg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
make[2]: *** [/home/pablo/ros_ws/devel/include/baxter_maintenance_msgs/CalibrateArmData.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [baxter_common/baxter_maintenance_msgs/CMakeFiles/baxter_maintenance_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Se espera a que terminen otras tareas....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/share/gencpp/cmake/../../../lib/gencpp/gen_cpp.py", line 41, in <module>
    import genmsg.template_tools
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genmsg/template_tools.py", line 39, in <module>
    import em
ImportError: No module named em
make[2]: *** [/home/pablo/ros_ws/devel/include/baxter_core_msgs/AnalogOutputCommand.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [baxter_common/baxter_core_msgs/CMakeFiles/baxter_core_msgs_generate_messages_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Could be this "ImportError: No module named em" related with the problem? I looked for this module on the web but could not find it , and apparently I could miss several dependences more.

Any comments and suggestions will be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200090/cannot-catkinify-baxter-sdk/) by [Liberona](https://answers.ros.org/users/21242/liberona/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2014-12-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`em` is the template engine used in several ROS packages and it can not be found in your case.
You can check if Python can find it by calling:

```
python -c "import em; print(em.__file__)"
```

Since you installed the Debian packages they depend on `python-empy` and therefore should have installed it.
Please verify that by running:

```
dpkg -l | grep python-empy
```

If that package is installed you should double check your Python path:

```
env | grep PYTHONPATH
python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2015-12-28**:
I got the same error, and when I checked the variable PYTHONPATH, it was without the path of the OS python distribution, but it had the path of the ROS distribution python and of the PACKAGE distribution python. Well, why my python path was without the OS python distribution???

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-12-29**:
`PYTHONPATH` only *augments* the import search path: https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH So it is expected that the "OS python distribution" is not on the `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try installing the empy package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-empy
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue is that you haven't installed something that are required to build `baxter` related packages from source (`em` in your case).
My guess is that you need to run something like the following (at the top of your `catkin workspace`) in order to redress the dependencies.

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro groovy -y -r
```

If this resolves the issue, I don't know why it's not included in the tutorial you referred to.

Btw for the questions regarding `Baxter Research Robot` you might get more eyes on [its email forum](https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/d/msg/brr-users/).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1